# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: html, dns, google-cloud-dns

I'am using google cloud platform to host my website www.mat.africa. I was connected yesterday on the cloud console, I didn't make any changes on the platform but now my website is showing a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN problem. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the domain "mat.africa" does not translate to any IP.

```
$ dig mat.africa

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> mat.africa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 33836
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

Checking the [domain availability](https://my.eurodns.com/das/search/) I see that it's in use but the Registry Expiration date is today.

```
Registry Expiry Date: 2020-06-08T17:00:36Z
```

I recommend you to contact your Registrar Provider to renew the domain or get more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to a DNS issue on your computer or home network.

https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-clear-dns-cache-on-mac/#Flush